# How to duplicate all inner columns of a matrix and sum pairs of columns in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-multiplication

Suppose I have a matrix `A`

```
 1     2     3     4     5
 1     2     3     4     5
 1     2     3     4     5
 1     2     3     4     5
 1     2     3     4     5
```

How do I duplicate the *inner* columns of `A` to get a new matrix `B`

```
 1     2     2     3     3     4     4     5
 1     2     2     3     3     4     4     5
 1     2     2     3     3     4     4     5
 1     2     2     3     3     4     4     5
 1     2     2     3     3     4     4     5
```

Notice the first and last column of `A` were left alone. Then I need to sum pairs of rows together to get another matrix `C`:

```
 3     5     7     9
 3     5     7     9
 3     5     7     9
 3     5     7     9
 3     5     7     9
```

1. The size of my matrices will not always be `5x5` and the elements will not always be so nice, but the matrix will always be square.
2. I *do not* need to generate or output matrix `B`. That was just simply how I initially thought of obtaining my final matrix `C`.
3. My goal is to be reasonably efficient, so I would like to accomplish this **without** a for loop.

How do I accomplish this for arbitrary matrix size  `nxn` ?

Comment: Do you need to generate `B` for anything other than generating `C`? Otherwise I'd question the efficiency of that intermediate step.

Comment: @learnvst No, but that's how I was thinking about it in my head. I suppose other than for debugging purposes, I wouldn't need it. I'll append a note. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very simple .  .

```
C = A(:,2:end) + A(:,1:end-1)
```